# Converting "IN" keyword in Oracle procedure to equivalent logic in Netezza stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, keyword, netezza

How can the following "IN" keyword be converted from this Oracle PL/SQL code below to Netezza SQL code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1 (typ IN VARCHAR, str IN VARCHAR) as

p1 varchar(50);
p2 number(9);
p3 char(1);

BEGIN 

-- CODE GOES HERE

END SP1
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the `IN` keyword, since that's the default in Oracle PL/SQL anyway?

Comment: Removing "IN" didn't work

Comment: From a quick search you don't give the formal arguments names either, you just specify the types; then refer to them as $1 etc. in the code. Not something I've used though so maybe it's optional. It would probably be helpful to show the code you're actually running and the errors you get.

Comment: Our Oracle box is down right now.  When it's up I'll get the latest code, and confirm the code works in Oracle and then post the whole code block.  This was code I wasn't able to get working during a conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netezza's parameter list are all input only, and are referenced by position.

You link the positional inputs to meaninful names with an ALIAS in the DECLARE block.  These parameters are constant in the scope of the procedure.

The p_ naming is a style convention only, and is meant to remind you that they are constant.  Variables are often prefixed as v_.

Here's a quick mapping of to Netezza for your code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1 (VARCHAR(any), VARCHAR(any))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
p_typ ALIAS FOR $1;
p_str ALIAS FOR $2;

v_1 varchar(50);
v_2 bigint;  -- changed this to be a valid Netezza for the example
v_3 char(1);

BEGIN

-- CODE GOES HERE



END;

END_PROC;
```